# Copy Entire List to New List

Tags: 2013, workflow, javascript, custom-list

This seems to be very simple but can't think of how to approach the task.  I want to create an exact copy of another custom list.  This can be done by creating a template BUT I want as items are added to Custom List A I want the information to be updated in the copy list created automatically.  I am thinking this can be done using a workflow but would that mean I have to create a Copy Item action for every column?  Can anyone help me?

Comment: I can't think of any reason you would need data multiplication within SharePoint. What do you need this for? :)

Comment: If you really want to do this, then yes Workflows or by using EventReceivers

Comment: @Gintas K You are probably thinking that views are the way to go and you are right!  For audit purposes I want to have Custom List A has the original and the copy as the copy.  I hope this makes sense. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

One solution for this could be to have a daily back up of your list that gets restored to the duplicated list (Using PowerShell).

1. Create a new subsite to store your duplicated list
2. Use Export-SPWeb command to take a backup of your main list
3. Use Import-SPWeb command to restore that list to the duplicated list.

More details on the commands :
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fromthefield/2016/07/14/export-spweb-exporting-lists/

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you need:

```
private SPListItem CopyItem(SPListItem sourceItem, string destinationListName) {
    //Copy sourceItem to destinationList
    SPList destinationList = sourceItem.Web.Lists[destinationListName];
    SPListItem targetItem = destinationList.Items.Add();
    foreach (SPField f in sourceItem.Fields) {
        //Copy all except attachments.
        if (!f.ReadOnlyField && f.InternalName != "Attachments"
            && null != sourceItem[f.InternalName])
        {
            targetItem[f.InternalName] = sourceItem[f.InternalName];
        }
    }
    //Copy attachments
    foreach (string fileName in sourceItem.Attachments) {
        SPFile file = sourceItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFile(sourceItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + fileName);
        byte[] imageData = file.OpenBinary();
        targetItem.Attachments.Add(fileName, imageData);
    }

    return targetItem;
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075323/copy-list-items-from-one-list-to-another-in-sharepoint)